# jQuery Mobile add list element

Tags: jquery, list, jquery-mobile, mobile, addition

I am wondering what I am doing wrong..

I have this ul:

```
<ul id="songlist" data-role="listview" data-divider-theme="b" data-inset="true">
<li data-role="list-divider" role="heading">
    Crowdlist
</li>
```

and this function for adding a list item:

```
function insertItem(myid,position,newListItem) {
    var ul = document.getElementById(myid);
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.innerHTML=newListItem;
    ul.insertBefore(li, ul.getElementsByTagName("li")[position]);
    }
```

calling the function like that:

```
insertItem('songlist',1,'<li data-theme="c" onclick="vote('+song+')">'+interpret+" - "+songtitle+'</li>');
```

adds a list element, but not looking like jQuery list elements I can add with

```
<li data-theme="c">dewf</li>
```

I just cant figure it out.. hope someone can help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to refresh the listview after you dynamically inject data it. After you've inserted data into `listview`, `trigger` a `create` on your `page`:

```
$("[data-role=page]").trigger("create");
```

**EDIT**

Based on the problem you're facing, i think the `refresh` isnt the right solution for you. You can't add `data-theme` attribute to an `li`. You'll have to add it to the `ul` (`li`'s parent).

Demo : [Javascript Version](http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/TdHXL/1/).

I tried to stick to JS as much as possible. But why? You're including jQuery and jQuery mobile, why not use it when you have it? If you want a jQuery solution, look at this version of your solution.

Demo : [jQuery Version](http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/TdHXL/2/).

Comment: So you mean I have to refresh the jQuery view? Because the new listelement appears correctly as html element